# Given two binary trees, calculate their diff

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

A friend of mine was asked this question in an interview.

Given two binary trees, explain how would you create a diff such that **if you have that diff and either of the trees you should be able to generate the other binary tree**. Implement a function `createDiff(Node tree1, Node tree 2)` returns that diff.

```
Tree 1
       4
     /   \
    3     2
   / \   /  \
  5   8 10   22

Tree 2
       1
         \
          4
         /  \
       11   12
```

If you are given Tree 2 and the diff you should be able to generate Tree 1.

My solution:
Convert both the binary trees into array where left child is at `2n+1` and right child is at `2n+2`and represent empty node by -1. Then just do element-wise subtraction of the array to create the diff. This solution will fail if tree has -1 as node value and I think there has to be a better and neat solution but I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: Based on the specification alone, your diff could just be Tree 1. Is there no other restriction or requirement specified?

Comment: How? You can't generate Tree2 from just Tree1

Comment: It didn't say you need to generate Tree2, but if you do, make the "diff" the pair of trees, if you're given one, return the other.

Comment: It says in the description - "if you have that diff and either of the trees you should be able to generate the other binary tree". If we store pair then we are kind of storing both trees in memory, I don't think that's the right solution.

Comment: Well, I don't either, but what I'm pointing to is that without any further information, technically what I suggested should be accepted. Are you sure there is no other information provided with this task?

Comment: Yeah, no other info. But I think this info is enough to create a diff.

Comment: @crysis I think **diff tree** can contain XOR of values of both trees. This works if both trees had same structure. If they have a different structure, XOR still holds but you will need to have additional attributes to decide whether to traverse further down to get the other tree or not.

Comment: Did any of the answers suit your needs? Could you leave some feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Think of them as direcory tres and print a sorted list of the path to every leaf item

Tree 1 becomes:

```
4/2/10
4/2/22
4/3/5
4/3/8
```

These list formats can be [diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)'ed and the tree recreated from such a list.

Comment: This will work, but if the top value changes then everything will be part of the diff.

Comment: Yes. Vim is your friend, I use it to edit in simple hierarchy changes such as node renames/insertions and then diffing. That's with a hundred thousand leafs or more coverage or netlist data from chip designs.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

I would suggest that you turn the tree into a sorted array of triples of `(parent, child, direction)`.  So start with tree1:

```
       4
     /   \
    3     2
   / \   /  \
  5   8 10   22
```

This quickly becomes:

```
(None, 4, None) # top
(4, 3, L)
(3, 5, L)
(3, 8, L)
(4, 2, R)
(2, 10, L)
(2, 22, R)
```

Which you sort to get

```
(None, 4, None) # top
(2, 10, L)
(2, 22, R)
(3, 5, L)
(3, 8, L)
(4, 2, R)
(4, 3, L)
```

Do the same with the other, and then diff them.

Given a tree and the diff, you can first turn the tree into this form, look at the diff, realize which direction it is and get the desired representation with patch.  You can then reconstruct the other tree recursively.

The reason why I would do it with this representation is that if the two trees share any subtrees in common - even if they are placed differently in the main tree - those will show up in common.  And therefore you are likely to get relatively small diffs if the trees do, in fact, match in some interesting way.

---

Edit

Per point from @ruakh, this does assume that values do not repeat in a tree.  If they do, then you could do a representation like this:

```
       4
     /   \
    3     2
   / \   /  \
  5   8 10   22
```

becomes

```
(, 4)
(0, 3)
(00, 5)
(01, 8)
(1, 2)
(10, 10)
(11, 22)
```

And now if you move subtrees, they will show up as large diffs.  But if you just change one node, it will still be a small diff.

Comment: This answer seems to assume that no two nodes in the same tree will have the same value?

Comment: @ruakh Correct.  I read the numbers as identifiers for the node.  It might be therefore better to use a representation of `(position, value)`.  Where positions are binary strings.  So instead of `(3, 5, L)` to simply say `(00, 3)` and `(000, 5)`.

Answer (score 0):

(The example from the question(/interview) is not very helpful in not showing any shared sub-structure of non-trivial size. Or the interview question outstanding for initiating a dialogue between customer and developer.)
Re-use of subtrees needs a representation allowing to identify such. It seems useful to be able to reconstruct the smaller tree without walking most of the difference. Denoting "definition" of identifiable sub-trees with capital letters and *re-use* by a tacked-on ':

```
     d            e             d--------e
  c     b "-"   c    b   =>   C   B'   C'  b
 b a   a       b a    a      B a            a
a             a             a
```

(The problem statement does *not* say *diff is linear*.)
Things to note:

- there's a sub-tree *B* occurring in two places of T1
- in T2, there's another *b* with one leaf-child *a* that is *not* another occurrence of *B*
- no attempt to share leaves

What if now I imagine (or the interviewer suggests) *two huge trees, identical but for one node somewhere in the middle which has a different value*?
Well, at least its sub-trees will be shared, and "the other sub-trees" all the way up to the root. Too bad if the trees are degenerated and almost all nodes are part of that path.
*Huge trees with children of the root exchanged?*
(Detecting trees occurring more than once has a chance to shine here.)
The bigger problem would seem to be the whole trees represented in "the diff", while the requirement may be

> Given one tree, the *diff* shall support reconstruction of the other using little space and processing.

(It might include *setting up the* diff *shall be cheap, too* - which I'd immediately challenge: *small diff* looks related to *editing distance*.)
A way to *identify* "crucial nodes" *in each tree* is needed - [btilly's suggestion of "left-right-string"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55247125) is good as gold.
Then, one would need a way to keep differences in children & value.

---

That's the far end I'd expect an exchange in an interview to reach.

To detect re-used trees, I'd add the *height* to each *internal node*. For a *proof of principle*, I'd probably use an existing implementation of *find repeated strings* on a suitable serialisation.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to think of a workable diff-structure.

### Naive solution

One naive way is to store the two trees in a tuple. Then, when you need to regenerate a tree, given the other and the diff, you just look for a node that is different when comparing the given tree with the tree in the first tuple entry of the diff. If found you return that tree from the first tuple entry. If not found, you return the second one from the diff tuple.

### Small diffs for small differences

An interviewer would probably ask for a less memory consuming alternative. One could try to think of a structure that will be small in size when there are only a few values or nodes different. In the extreme case where both trees are equal, such diff would be (near-)empty as well.

#### Definitions

I define these terms before defining the diff's structure:

- Imagine the trees get extra NIL leaf nodes, i.e. an empty tree would consist of 1 NIL node. A tree with only a root node, would have two NIL nodes as its direct children, ...etc.
- A node is common to both trees when it can be reached via the same path from the root (e.g. left-left-right), irrespective of whether they contain the same value or have the same children. A node can even be common when it is a NIL node in one or both of the trees (as defined above).
- Common nodes (including NIL nodes when they are common) get a preorder sequence number (0, 1, 2, ...). Nodes that are *not* common are discarded during this numbering.

#### Diff structure

The difference could be a list of tuples, where each tuple has this information:

- The above mentioned preorder sequence number, identifying a common node
- A value: when neither nodes is a NIL node, this is the diff of the values (e.g. XOR). When one of the nodes is a NIL node, the value is the other node object (so effectively including the whole subtree below it). In typeless languages, either information can fit in the same tuple position. In strongly typed languages, you would use an extra entry in the tuple (e.g. atomicValue, subtree), where only one of two would have a significant value.

A tuple will only be added for a common node, and only when either their values differ, and at least one of both is a not-NIL node.

#### Algorithm

The diff can be created via a preorder walk through the common nodes of the trees.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value, left, right) {
        this.value = value;
        if (left) this.left = left;
        if (right) this.right = right;
    }
    clone() {
        return new Node(this.value, this.left ? this.left.clone() : undefined,
                                    this.right ? this.right.clone() : undefined); 
    }
}

// Main functions:
function createDiff(tree1, tree2) {
    let i = -1; // preorder sequence number
    function recur(node1, node2) {
        i++;
        if (!node1 !== !node2) return [[i, (node1 || node2).clone()]];
        if (!node1) return [];
        const result = [];
        if (node1.value !== node2.value) result.push([i, node1.value ^ node2.value]);
        return result.concat(recur(node1.left, node2.left), recur(node1.right, node2.right));
    }
    return recur(tree1, tree2);
}

function applyDiff(tree, diff) {
    let i = -1; // preorder sequence number
    let j = 0; // index in diff array
    function recur(node) {
        i++;
        let diffData = j >= diff.length || diff[j][0] !== i ? 0 : diff[j++][1];
        if (diffData instanceof Node) return node ? undefined : diffData.clone();
        return node && new Node(node.value ^ diffData, recur(node.left), recur(node.right));
    }
    return recur(tree);
}

// Create sample data:
let tree1 = 
    new Node(4,
        new Node(3,
            new Node(5), new Node(8)
        ),
        new Node(2,
            new Node(10), new Node(22)
        )
    );
let tree2 =
    new Node(2,
        undefined,
        new Node(4,
            new Node(11), new Node(12)
        )
    );

// Demo:
let diff = createDiff(tree1, tree2);
console.log("Diff:");
console.log(diff);

const restoreTree2 = applyDiff(tree1, diff);
console.log("Is restored second tree equal to original?");
console.log(JSON.stringify(tree2)===JSON.stringify(restoreTree2));

const restoreTree1 = applyDiff(tree2, diff);
console.log("Is restored first tree equal to original?");
console.log(JSON.stringify(tree1)===JSON.stringify(restoreTree1));

const noDiff = createDiff(tree1, tree1);
console.log("Diff for two equal trees:");
console.log(noDiff);
```